# How sort this list in netlogo

Tags: sorting, netlogo

I am trying to order the following list in netoglo:

```
[[0.1 [1 2 5 3 1]] [0.3 [1 2 1 3 1]] [0.2 [1 2 1 3 1]]]
```

Actually they are list lists and what I want is to sort by the first element of each sublist:

When I use `sort [[0.1 [1 2 5 3 1]] [0.3 [1 2 1 3 1]] [0.2 [1 2 1 3 1]]]`

It returns empty I suppose because it only sees lists and not anything so I sort.

Any ideas.

Comment: Just use `sort-by`, but first fix the first sublist.

Comment: But as I fix it, I need to keep the reference of the number with its sublist.

Comment: That's no problem.  But the use of commas is a problem.  
Just sort by the first element of each list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I did not see that there were commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to alan the answer was `show sort-by [first ?1 > first ?2][[0.1 [1 2 5 3 1]] [0.3 [1 2 1 3 1]] [0.2 [1 2 1 3 1]]]`

Comment: Note under NetLogo 6.0, this would be: `show sort-by [ [a b] -> first a > first b ] [[0.1 [1 2 5 3 1]] [0.3 [1 2 1 3 1]] [0.2 [1 2 1 3 1]]]`